# Drag and Drop DIV to any position within a cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm using the [REDIPS Drag and Drop JQuery PlugIN](http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/), that allows me to create draggable content that snaps to a defined table and its cells. However I need to change a bit in such a way that it allows me to drop an element anywhere in a cell, rather than just placing it by default at the end or the beginning.

So I still need to functionality where it "snaps content to a grid" but I need it to have any "left margin" within the dropped cell. Once the div is dropped in a cell i would like it get its left margin or offset from the parent cell.

**[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianfc89/JDff9/6/)**

```
var marginLeftAfterDrop = $("#" + divID).position.left;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are using REDIPS for the draggable feature but I highly suggest to use the plugin made by Jquery through this  [link](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to).

It is highly customizable and extendable according to your need. Moreover, it is highly supported by the community and plenty of developers are using it.

Comment: thanks for replying! so would i be able to replicate what i did above?

Comment: Hi Yes, you would be. Jquery has a a complete API regarding almost all of your UI concerns and it will be helpful if you will review the link that I gave above.